# How to decrease the time needed for calculating Granger causality with high lag length?

Tags: r, time

Explanation of used function and data:

- I am using function `grangertest(x ~ y, order =k)` , from package
  `lmtest`
- Each `time series (x,y) has` 1950 observations (first
  difference for intraday 1 minute stock prices).

Problem:

- When running `grangertest(x ~ y, order =k)` with very high k, such as
  300, it takes a long time for calculation. For example for `k = 300`, it takes 17 seconds to calculate Granger causality.

**Question:**

- **Is there a way to decrease calculating time?** This is important because I should run more than 8000 causality tests, meaning that duration of my calculations would be more than 37 hours.

Details about used platform:

- I use R version 3.0.3
- System Manufacturer  Dell Inc.
- System Model Inspiron M5030
- System Type  x64-based PC
- Processor    AMD Athlon(tm) II P340 Dual-Core Processor, 2200 Mhz, 2
  Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
- BIOS Version/Date    Dell Inc. A02, 8/5/2010
- SMBIOS Version   2.6
- Installed Physical Memory (RAM)  2.00 GB
- Total Physical Memory    1.75 GB
- Available Physical Memory    99.6 MB
- Total Virtual Memory 3.49 GB
- Available Virtual Memory 1.25 GB

Comment: You have a typo in your title: "Granger" causality, not "Garch" causality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a start for you with only necessary computations. It returns a p-value and F statistic only but you can easily modify it.

```
grangerfast <- function(y, x, k) {
  l1 <- embed(y, k + 1)
  l2 <- embed(x, k + 1)
  X1 <- cbind(1, l1[, -1])
  X2 <- cbind(X1, l2[, -1])
  Y <- l1[, 1]
  d <- diag(length(Y))
  rss1 <- sum(((d - X1 %*% solve(crossprod(X1)) %*% t(X1)) %*% Y)^2)
  rss2 <- sum(((d - X2 %*% solve(crossprod(X2)) %*% t(X2)) %*% Y)^2)
  Fstat <- ((rss1 - rss2) / k) / (rss2 / (length(Y) - (2 * k + 1)))
  c(pf(Fstat, k, length(Y) - (2 * k + 1), lower.tail = FALSE), Fstat)
}
set.seed(123)
y <- rnorm(2000)
x <- rnorm(2000)
system.time(print(grangerfast(y, x, 300)))
# [1] 0.6529602 0.9627089
#    user  system elapsed 
#   3.527   0.051   3.576 
system.time(print(grangertest(y ~ x, order = 300)))
# Granger causality test
# 
# Model 1: y ~ Lags(y, 1:300) + Lags(x, 1:300)
# Model 2: y ~ Lags(y, 1:300)
#   Res.Df   Df      F Pr(>F)
# 1   1099                   
# 2   1399 -300 0.9627  0.653
#    user  system elapsed 
#   8.958   0.226   9.188
```

It would be easy to check but probably matrix algebra takes most of the time. However, you might make it even faster. For example, in case you are performing this test for all pairs of stock prices, you could compute `l1`, `l2` and crossproducts only once. You could also parallelize this process. If you are running the test for the same pair and different `k`, then again you can save some time.

Comment: thank you for your help. Your code is working well and the running time is decreased by more than 2 times. Beside P-value I need F-value too. You are right, the P-value is not exactly the same as in grangertest(). Unfortunately, I cannot distinguish which part of code I should adjust in order to get the same value like in grangertest(). Do you mind if I will use your code to ask the question on how to get f-value too and the p-value like it is in grangertest()?

Comment: @RobinHood, I have modified the code so that F statistic is also returned. I don't mind you using my code but first I myself will take another look and will let you know if I can't find what to change.

Comment: @RobinHood, I fixed it, a constant term was missing in both models.

Answer (score 2):

Running time is often also linked with the amount of memory available; the less memory available, the slower a program runs.

You can increase the memory allocated to R using the command **memory.limit(size=...)**, the number of mb you wish to allocate (from experience, you can make this infinitely large)

Another way of improving your memory allocation is to constantly remove unneeded variables in your environment using the command **rm(...)** or using the garbage clean up command **gc()** which deletes a lot of unnecessary data usage which may have resulted from previous computations